# How to set an alternate posts_per_page value for default queries in different templates

Tags: wp-query, custom-taxonomy

I have a WP site with multiple post types.  Posts, products w/taxonomies.

I have my WP Default posts_per_page setting at 10 in the admin.  I want to keep this setting as the blog would be best at 10 per page.

However on a page/template like taxonomyNAme-archive.php I want to get many more than 10.  But I don't need a custom query, since WP knows what posts to get me.  Can I hijack the posts_per_page without writing a custom query?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`pre_get_posts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) action to modify query parameters before the queries are run. You can use many of the [Conditional Tags](https://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags) to target specific types of pages.

```
function wpd_alter_posts_per_page( $query ) {
    // don't alter admin or custom queries
    if ( is_admin() || ! $query->is_main_query() )
        return;

    // if this is your-custom-tax archive
    if ( is_tax( 'your-custom-tax' ) ) {
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 20 );
        return;
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpd_alter_posts_per_page' );
```

Answer (score 0):

*@TJ Sherrill*, as alternative of [*@Milo answer*](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/223156), WordPress say, *"If you want to alter the value of an option during the rendering of a page without changing it permanently in the database you can use* [`pre_option_(option name)`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/pre_option_%28option_name%29).

Here the sample code related to your issue, using [`is_tax`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_tax) as conditional taxonomy:

```
add_filter( 'pre_option_posts_per_page', 'limit_posts_per_page' );
function limit_posts_per_page( $posts_per_page )
{
    /* taxonomy "genre" with term "romantic" */
    if ( is_tax( 'genre', 'romantic' ) ) 
        return 11;
    return $posts_per_page;
}
```

Just tweak the condition tag that suit with your need.